# problems with alfresco performance

Tags: server, alfresco

I have a performance problem on a server that contains the Alfresco document manager. From one day to another, the use of the CPU is 95% fixed, with the command that Alfresco launches to execute. I have tried to change the garbage collector, change the JVM, optimize the threads, but I do not get any improvement.

The alfresco version is the Community

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Hi, your problem is not very clear for me, you should explain it more clearly. Please show us your logs.
But, by experience, I've faced 95% CPU saturation when Alfresco was trying to transform a document for indexing which was too big for it to process, leading to a cancel of the transformation, and an immediate retry, indefinetly. You could activate the logs for the transform part to see that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very hard to answer with the little information that is provided. CPU problems could be caused by a bad transformation, but it can also be caused by several other factors. Luis Colorado did a nice presentation on performance at DevCon 2019. You can check out [his presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/LuisColoradoSCJP/alfresco-devcon-2019-performance-tools-of-the-trade) for some tips.

A general piece of advice is to make sure you have Alfresco's Tomcat, SOLR, and the database all running on different machines. Those all have very different performance profiles, so keeping them separate allows you to tune them individually.